# AngularJS inheritance - overwrite $scope.method()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

I have a ParentController and a ChildController, which look like this:

`ParentController`:

```
app.controller("ParentController", function($scope) {

    // define preload method, expose to template
    $scope.preload = function() {
        console.log("parent");
    };

    // call preload function
    $scope.preload();
});
```

`ChildController`:

```
app.controller("ChildController", function($scope) {
    $controller("ParentController", {
        $scope: $scope,
    });

    // override preload method here
    $scope.preload = function() {
        console.log("child")
    };
});
```

As you can see, both Controllers define `$scope.preload()`, which is called upon instantiation in the `ParentController`. My goal is for `ChildController`to overwrite this method, so that when it is called, it logs a different string to the console.

Is this possible? If not, how else would I go about reusing all methods defined in `ParentController`in my `ChildController`?

Comment: reusable components should go in services/factory and not in controller.

Comment: Could you elaborate further, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To share the data among independent controllers, Services can be used. Create a service with the data model that needs to be shared. Inject the service in the respective controllers.

In the following example, Service is used to store the variable x. The independent controllers will check the value of X whenever needed.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .service('myService', function () {
        var x=5 ;
        return {
            increase : function() {
                x++;
            },
            getX : function() {
                return x;
            }
       };
    })

function ControllerA($scope, myService) {
    $scope.x = 1;
    $scope.incrementDataInService= function() {
        myService.increase();
    }
    $scope.syncDataWithService= function() {
        $scope.x = myService.getX();
    }        
}

function ControllerB($scope, myService) {
   $scope.x = 1;
    $scope.incrementDataInService= function() {
        myService.increase();            
    }
    $scope.syncDataWithService= function() {
        $scope.x = myService.getX();
    }    
}​
```

Comment: What about working with `$scope.member` inside the service? Will I have to pass it as a parameter or can I reuse whatever `$scope` is inside the Controller?

Comment: pass it as a parameter, but not $scope, pass the parameter you are working with...

Comment: dont pass $scope, pass the parameter on which the logic depends.. passing $scope is a code smell